# Conservative fields and not simply connected domains

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm given a continuously differentiable $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ , we define a function $\vec{F}:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ by:
$\vec{F}( \vec{x} ) =f(|| \vec{x} || ) \vec{x} $ .

The question is:
Prove that $\vec{F}$ is a conservative field and find its potential.

I guess that if I'll find a potential , it will prove that the function is conservative.
But, how can I find a potential for this vector field ? (I guess it will depend on $f$ in an integral manner)

What do you think ? Is there any difference between the $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ case and $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3 $ (i.e.- will the same argument work in other dimensions?)

Thanks !

Comment: *Hint:* If $g$ is a potential of $\vec F$, then $g(\vec x) = g(\vec y) + \int_{\vec y}^{\vec x} \vec F\cdot\mathrm d\vec x$ (or minus, depending on your sign convention) for any point $\vec y$ and any path integral from $\vec y$ to $\vec x$. You get to pick the $\vec y$. You get to pick the path. Do any particular choices look convenient to you, given the form of $\vec F$?

Comment: Hi @RahulNarain . Thanks for the hint, but I'm still a little bit confused. 
Because of the given form of $\vec{F}$ , I would say that we might want to pick a circular curve, becuase of the dependence on the radius. The problem is that I can't see how it helps me. WIll you agree to give me a more detailed explanation ? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that a field is conservative iff it's rotor-free. Let's note $r=\|x\|$.
First, our field is continuous everywhere - it's a product of two continuous functions.

Now, let's prove that its gradient is also continuous everywhere. It writes

$$\nabla F = \begin{pmatrix}F_{1,1}& F_{1,2}\\F_{2,1}& F_{2,2} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{x^2}{r}f'(r)+f(r)& \frac{xy}{r}f'(r)\\\frac{xy}{r}f'(r)& \frac{y^2}{r}f'(r)+f(r)\end{pmatrix}.$$
Clearly, this matrix is continuous on $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$. Now we claim that this matrix is continuous everywhere. Indeed, its limit when $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ is easily found, it equals 
$$\begin{pmatrix} f(0)& 0\\0& f(0)\end{pmatrix}.$$ (here we use that fact that $f\in C^1$; the easiest way to find this limit is to pass to polar coordinates)

Therefore, we can conclude that $\nabla F$ is continuous on the whole space and, hence, that $F$ is $C^1$ on the whole space.

So we need to look at $$ \text{curl } F = (\partial_1 F_2-\partial_2F_1) = x_2 f'(r)\frac{x_1}{r} -x_1 f'(r)\frac{x_2}{r}=0.$$ Therefore, our field is indeed rotor-free **on the whole space** and hence it's conservative.

The potential $G$ is defined up to an additive constant, so let's put $G(0)=0$. Then again,
if $G_{\vec y}(t):=G(t\vec y)$:
$$G(\vec y) = \int_{0}^1 G'_{\vec y}(t)dt = \int_{0}^1 \nabla G(t\vec y)\cdot\vec y dt $$
$$=\int_{0}^1 F(t\vec y)\cdot\vec y dt=\int_{0}^1 f(\|t\vec y\|)t\vec y\cdot\vec y dt =\|\vec y\|^2 \int_{0}^1 f(t\|\vec y\|)t  dt $$

Comment: @TZakarevskiy: notice, that $r=0$ in $(0,0)$ , so we actually have that the field is rotor-free in a non-simply-connected space $\mathbb{R}^2 - (0,0)$ and it gives us nothing (in non-simply-connected regions, this is only a necessary condition, but not sufficient).
I also can't understand the last equality in your last calculation of the potential. you took an arbitrary point in space. Then, in the first equality, you used theorem about directional derivative of diff functions. afterwards, you used the fact that $G$ is out potential

Comment: , but I can't understand how you arrived to the last equality... Hope you'll be able to help me . Thanks

Comment: @criticism I edited my answer to answer your remarks. If you still have questions, just ask=)

Comment: @TZzkarevskiy: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I still can't understand how you write that the matrix is continuous if it is not even defined in $(0,0)$ ... We work in all $\mathbb{R}^2-(0,0)$, but can't work in $(0,0)$ because our function is not differentiable there... Will you please agree to help me understand this ? Thanks again

Comment: @criticism see edits.

Comment: @TZzkareskiy: I guess you meant that $\nabla F$ has a removable singularity in $(0,0)$ , and not that it is continuous. In any case, I think I got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

The given field is rotationally symmetric. It is not unreasonable to assume that a possible potential $(x,y)\mapsto V(x,y)$ is rotationally symmetric as well. Therefore make the "Ansatz"
$$V(x,y)=v\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\bigr)$$
with a function $v$ of one variable, and check whether this leads somewhere.

Comment: OK. I get:"
$\frac{v'(||\vec{x}||)}{||\vec{x}||}=f(||\vec{x}||) $ . How does this help me ? 
Thanks a lot !